# Ctrl-y not restoring line in zsh

Tags: zsh, clipboard

I've got zsh 5.8.1 running on Ubuntu 22.04.  When I've got some text on the prompt and I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, it clears the line as expected.  However, when I then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, it only displays

```bash
$ ^Y
```

What could be causing the readline buffer not to be pasted?

Here's my .zshrc:

```bash
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME=""

plugins=(
    colored-man-pages
    colorize
    git
    zsh-autosuggestions
    zsh-interactive-cd
    vi-mode
)

ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_STRATEGY=(history completion)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
unalias ls
unalias ll
unalias lsa

unalias gst
alias gs='git status'
alias gcob='git checkout -b'

bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
bindkey "^[." insert-last-word

_sig_array=($(kill -l))

_return_status() {
    ret=$?
    if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
        if [ $ret -le 128 ]; then
            echo $ret
        else
            sig=$(( $ret - 128 ))
            desc=$_sig_array[sig]
            if [ "$desc" != INT -a "$desc" != TSTP ]; then
                echo SIG$desc
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

_return_status_formatted() {
    out=$(_return_status)
    if [ -n "$out" ]; then
        echo "%F{red}[$out]%f "
    fi
}

_current_branch_formatted() {
    out=$(current_branch)
    if [ -n "$out" ]; then
        if [ -n "$(git status -s | grep -v '^\?')" ]; then
            color=magenta
        else
            color=cyan
        fi
        echo "%F{$color}(git:$out)%f "
    fi
}

export PS1='%F{blue}%n%f@%F{green}%m%f:%F{red}%~%f $ $(_return_status_formatted)$(_current_branch_formatted)'
```

Comment: The `zsh` shell does not use Readline, to my knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong term.  Is the emacs-style <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> functionality tied to readline?

Comment: Are you using the `emacs` mode? (`bindkey -e`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zsh` will use `vi` key bindings by default if the `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` variable contains `vi` (it then assumes you prefer `vi`).

`^Y` to paste is an emacs key binding (the `vi` equivalent would be `p`/`P`).

Add a:

```
bindkey -e
```

to your `~/.zshrc` to indicate that you want emacs key bindings regardless of your editor choice (same as in `tcsh`). Or `set -o emacs` (same as in ksh).

---

Some other notes on your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey "^[." insert-last-word
```

is already there by default in `emacs` mode, so you shouldn't need that.

There's already a builtin `$signals` array (beware it starts at `EXIT` == 0, so you need `$signals[signum+1]` to get the name from the number).

Behaviour for `grep -v '^\?'` is unspecified. Use `grep -v '^?'` to remove the lines that start with `?`, or `grep -v '^\\?'` to remove the ones that start with `\?`.

It's a good habit to declare variables `local` to your functions if they're not intended to be global.

See also `[[ $desc = (INT|TSTP) ]] || echo SIG$desc`.

Generally, like in other shells, the `-a` operator of the `[` builtin is deprecated.

Here, you could use `((...))` consistently:

```
_return_status() {
    local sig desc ret="$?"
    if (( ret != 0 )); then
        if (( ret <= 128 )); then
            echo $ret
        else
            (( sig = ret - 128 ))
            desc=$signals[sig+1]
            if [[ $desc != (INT|TSTP) ]] echo SIG$desc
        fi
    fi
}
```